# Download Attachment from Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this code in Outlook VBA ThisOutlookSession, it is not giving any error, but is not downloading the attachments. Any idea

```
Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Set objInboxItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub
Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
   Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
   Dim strSenderAddress As String
   Dim strSenderDomain As String
   Dim objAttachment As Attachment
   Dim strFolderPath As String
   Dim strFileName As String

   If Item.Class = olMail Then
      Set objMail = Item

      'Get sender domain
      strSenderAddress = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
      strSenderDomain = Right(strSenderAddress, Len(strSenderAddress) - InStr(strSenderAddress, "@"))

      'Change to the specific domain as per your needs
      If strSenderDomain = "gmail.com" Then
       If strSenderAddress = "vs@gmail.com" Then
         If objMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            For Each objAttachment In objMail.Attachments
                strFolderPath = "E:\Cisco - Qutar\Performance Report Automation\"
                strFileName = objMail.Subject & " " & Chr(45) & " " & objAttachment.FileName
                objAttachment.SaveAsFile strFolderPath & strFileName
            Next
         End If
      End If
   End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Updated now

Comment: hi. in the line If strSenderDomain = "vs@gmail.com" Then u expect to get vs@gmail.com, but the var strSenderDomain is iqual to the domain gmail.com... change the  "vs@gmail.com" to  "gmail.com" and should work

Comment: Hi Luis, I need it for a specific sender only, there are may emails that come in form diff user's if doing so it will download all the mails from gmail senders. ''' If strSenderDomain = "gmail.com"', still not downloading

Comment: in that case change --> If strSenderDomain = "vs@gmail.com" Then <-- to --> If strSenderAddress = "vs@gmail.com" Then <--. U cant compare an email address with the domain..

Comment: Have changed it, but still no luck, ''' If strSenderAddress = "vs@gmail.com" Then '''

Comment: does it enter in that if ? and in the for each ?

Comment: This is my code below now  If strSenderDomain = "gmail.com" Then
       If strSenderAddress = "vs@gmail.com" Then

Comment: u have write gmai.com. i dont know if is a typo. can u do a F8 to see if the code enters in the for each cycle ?

Comment: sorry, done the changes, for gmail.com

Comment: Luis, you can check my code , I have updated the modifications.

Comment: it seems ok. ill ask you again. when you run the code does it enters in that IF's and in the FOR EACH ?

Comment: Luis, it runs in IF's

Answer (score 0):

*Set up your [Application_Startup()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.startup) the following*

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub
```

Comment: error on '''  Set Items = Inbox.Items ''' object not defined

Comment: object is defined, look at 2nd line on answer code @vmjan02

Comment: I am still getting the same error for  Set Items = Inbox.Items error as Variable not defined.